# How to use libraries used by a library in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, shared-libraries

I have a library that used a lot of libraries, now I want to use my library in a project and do not add libraries used by my library in the project and use the libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to change the `build.gradle` of the 'parent' library, then you can add the 'child' library dependencies using `api`,

```
dependencies {
    api 'child:dependency:1'
    api 'child:dependency:2'
    ...
}
```

this will 'leak' the dependencies so that you can directly use them in your application.

Refer to this [article](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa) for a more indepth explanation on what the difference between `implementation` and `api` is (which should help you understand why `api` is what you need).

Comment: thanks for your answer, where are you from? And on which social network can I talk to you?

Comment: You're welcome. India. StackOverflow. (I don't really frequent any other social networks often)

Comment: Nice to meet you